# OR operator collection issue

Tags: magento-1, query

This is my collection:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
                    ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                    ->joinAttribute('billing_street', 'customer_address/street', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                    ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                    ->addFieldToFilter('billing_city', ['like' => '%'.$customer->getAddresses()[0]->getData('city').'%'])
                    ->addFieldToFilter('billing_street' , ['like' => '%'.$customer->getAddresses()[0]->getData('street').'%'])
                    ->addFieldToFilter('billing_telephone', ['like' => '%'.$customer->getAddresses()[0]->getData('telephone').'%'])
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('email', array('neq' => $customer->getData('email')))
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(['email', 'firstname', 'lastname'])
```

This generates me a query condition with AND . I want to change it into OR for  3 elements `billing_city` or `billing_street` or `billing_telephone`. I tried this:

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
                    ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                    ->joinAttribute('billing_street', 'customer_address/street', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                    ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
                    ->addFieldToFilter(
                        ['billing_city', 'billing_street', 'billing_telephone'],
                        [
                            ['like' => '%'.$customer->getAddresses()[0]->getData('city').'%'],
                            ['like' => '%'.$customer->getAddresses()[0]->getData('street').'%'],
                            ['like' => '%'.$customer->getAddresses()[0]->getData('telephone').'%'],
                        ]
                    )
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('email', array('neq' => $customer->getData('email')))
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(['email', 'firstname', 'lastname']);
```

but when I want to display the query with `getSelect()` I got this message:
`invalid Attributname: a`

Comment: Try removing comma after `['like' => '%'.$customer->getAddresses()[0]->getData('telephone').'%'],`

Comment: @Nalin I did , still the same `invalid attribute name: a` . Don't ask me why `a` :)